# Use of an OFL font in a logotype

Tags: fonts, logo, font-licensing

Can I use a font licensed under the SIL OFL in a logo, and should I add a copyright notice then?

Comment: Its not a font file once you outline it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the FAQ](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#c26665c2):

> **Question:** 1.1 Can I use the fonts for a book or other print publication, to create logos or other graphics or even to manufacture objects based on their outlines?
>
> **Answer:** Yes. You are very welcome to do so. Authors of fonts released under the OFL allow you to use their font software as such for any kind of design work. No additional license or permission is required, unlike with some other licenses. Some examples of these uses are: logos, posters, business cards, stationery, video titling, signage, t-shirts, personalised fabric, 3D-printed/laser-cut shapes, sculptures, rubber stamps, cookie cutters and lead type.

I'm not sure what you are asking about in regards to copyright. FYI, logos aren't usually copyrighted, but instead registered as trademarks.

Answer (score 0):

In the US typefaces can't be copyrighted (only the font file itself). So I don't think you have to.

Comment: Please provide a reference to your claim.